# Two engine codes 18DAF110. 18DAF118

Tags: computer, code, range-rover

I have a 2008 Range Rover HSE 4.4 engine and I got a control module code 18DAF110 and another code 18DAF118 could you let me know what these codes mean thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: its numbers of control units. not faults